# Python-Tkinter-Basic login form

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am trying to make a basic login form. I'm having trouble with passing values to my function which checks the username and password.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)#Set __init__ to the master class
        self.grid()
        self.create_main()#Creates function

    def create_main(self):
        print("testing")
        self.title = Label(self, text=" Stuck In The Circle ")#TITLE 
        self.title.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.user_entry_label = Label(self, text="Username: ")#USERNAME LABEL
        self.user_entry_label.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.user_entry = Entry(self)                        #USERNAME ENTRY BOX
        self.user_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.pass_entry_label = Label(self, text="Password: ")#PASSWORD LABEL
        self.pass_entry_label.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.pass_entry = Entry(self)                        #PASSWORD ENTRY BOX
        self.pass_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.sign_in_butt = Button(self, text="Sign In",command = self.logging_in)#SIGN IN BUTTON
        self.sign_in_butt.grid(row=5, column=2)

    def logging_in(self):
        print("hi")
        user_get = user_entry.get()#Retrieve Username
        pass_get = pass_entry.get()#Retrieve Password

        if user_get == 'sam':
            if pass_get == '123':
                print("Welcome!")






#Main
root = Tk()
root.title("Stuck in the Circle")
root.geometry("400x100")

app = Application(root)#The frame is inside the widgit
root.mainloop()#Keeps the window open/running
```

Here is my error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1549, in call return self.func(*args) File "C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/Computer Science/Python/Python- Modules/Tkinter/Tkinter Projects/Login Form GUI.py", line 31, in logging_in user_get = user_entry.get()#Retrieve Username NameError: name 'user_entry' is not defined

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/Computer Science/Python/Python- Modules/Tkinter/Tkinter Projects/Login Form GUI.py", line 31, in logging_in
    user_get = user_entry.get()#Retrieve Username
NameError: name 'user_entry' is not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I integrate TKinter with Python log in screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156719/how-can-i-integrate-tkinter-with-python-log-in-screen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def logging_in(self):
    print("hi")
    user_get = self.user_entry.get()#Retrieve Username
    pass_get = self.pass_entry.get()#Retrieve Password
```

use `self.user_entry.get()`

When you are calling class variables, you need to call it by `self.variable_name`

Comment: Thank-you so much man! I have been working on this for hours now and I feel so stupid! The code is all working like I wanted it to. I really appreciate your help :D Have a good day!

Comment: no problem :) please pick best answer when you get a chance!