# I want to make a small database and make that you need a password to get into the main database screen

Tags: python, tkinter

my name is Victor and I am 15 years old. I am very new to coding and need some help :) I am currently working on a database for me to save my passwords and user information. I am at the point where the database is working fine. I don't know how to make that my toplevel in tkinter is accessible and my root window is not and I don't know how to check if the password that was entered in the password box is the correct password.

```
import sqlite3

root = Tk()

root.title("LOGBOOK")
root.iconbitmap("C:/Users/victo/Pictures/logo2.ico")
top = Toplevel()
top.iconbitmap("C:/Users/victo/Pictures/logo2.ico")

conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")

c = conn.cursor()


# create function delete
def delete():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("DELETE from logdata WHERE oid = " + delete_b.get())

    conn.commit()

    conn.close()


# create function submit
def submit():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO logdata VALUES (:username_email, :password, :game_website)",
              {
                  'username_email': username_email.get(),
                  'password': password.get(),
                  'game_website': game_website.get()
              })

    conn.commit()

    conn.close()

    username_email.delete(0, END)
    password.delete(0, END)
    game_website.delete(0, END)


# create function query
def query():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM logdata")
    records = c.fetchall()

    print_records = ''
    for record in records:
        print_records += str(record[0]) + " " + str(record[1]) + " " + "\t" + str(record[3]) + "\n"

    query_lab = Label(root, text=print_records)
    query_lab.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=2)
    conn.commit()

    conn.close()


# creating a table
# c.execute("""CREATE TABLE logdata (
#        username_email text,
#        password text,
#        game_website text
#        )""")

# entry area
admpw = Entry(top, width=30)
admpw.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=30)

username_email = Entry(root, width=30)
username_email.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=30)

password = Entry(root, width=30)
password.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=30)

game_website = Entry(root, width=30)
game_website.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=30)

delete_b = Entry(root, width=30)
delete_b.grid(row=6, column=1)
# labels
uemail_label = Label(root, text="Username or E-mail")
uemail_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

password_label = Label(root, text="Password")
password_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

game_label = Label(root, text="Game or website")
game_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

delete_label = Label(root, text="OID number")
delete_label.grid(row=6, column=0)
# create buttons
submit = Button(root, text="Add to database", command=submit)
submit.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=100)

query = Button(root, text="Show records", command=query)
query.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=108)

delete = Button(root, text="delete a record", command=delete)
delete.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=103)

login = Button(top, text="Open and access database!")
login.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

admpw = Label(top, text="Admin Password: ")
admpw.grid(row=0, column=0)

pw = admpw.get()

if pw == 1234:
    top.destroy()



conn.commit()

conn.close()

root.mainloop()
```

this is what the code looks like rn.

I would be really happy if someone could help me.

Comment: Hey victor, your database looks great. There is one issue though, having a database without hashing passwords is not good. If you actually want to use this database it is important that you hash passwords, otherwise malicious actors can exploit your database and steal your passwords.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking about that but I started coding 2 days ago and this is my first real project. If you could give me some tips maybe how to hash the passwords or if you know how, how I can make that I need a password to get into the database.

Comment: Hey, that's a great start Victor! I can try to help! i am still confused about what the problem is - is it verifying the password is in the database?

Comment: I want to make a second window where you need to enter a admin password to enter the database. My problem is that I don‘t know how to make the main window inaccessible if you don‘t enter the password or enter a wrong password. And I don’t know how to check if it is the right password that was entered.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the updates in the comments, I would have a while loop to check the password and have this be in a login window which would be the first thing in the code. 
more can be read about this here: [How can I integrate Tkinter with Python log in screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156719/how-can-i-integrate-tkinter-with-python-log-in-screen)

Comment: Okay, thank you I‘m gonna take a look at that and try to figure it out.

Comment: consider upvoting my answer and comments if they are helpful :) best of luck. post again on this thread if you need more help